# Android ConstraintLayout getWidth return 0

Tags: android

I use ConstraintLayout in my project. While I find a problem when I try to call getWidth in onCreate. The result is 0.

The code is here.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paint);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    iv.setOnTouchListener(new ImageViewTouchListener());

    System.out.println("imageview width:" + iv.getWidth() + " height:" + iv.getHeight());
}
```

[The layout design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvZyA.jpg)

The xml content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_red"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_green"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn_red" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_blue"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn_green"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.09784412" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sb_stroke"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_green" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="103dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1840796" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:background="#22000000"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to know how to get the right width and height of ImageView.

I try to get width and height in onStart and onResume but get the same result 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getWidth() and getHeight() of View returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0)

Comment: what was the question? the question and its answer could be important to someone else

Comment: This is a silly question. So I rewrite it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Its because your view is not been created yet.

```
  iv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 //height is ready
                 System.out.println("imageview width:" + iv.getWidth() + " height:" + iv.getHeight());
            }
        });
```

Comment: you are welcome:)

Answer (score 7):

In `OnCreate()` your `view` has not yet been created as per your `xml` parameters. So you have to add `addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` on your view and you will get your dimensions in that `listener` once `view` has been created.

```
iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    System.out.println("imageview width:" + iv.getWidth() + " height:" + iv.getHeight());
   }
});
```

Comment: The method is useful. But this method was deprecated in API level 16. Use #removeOnGlobalLayoutListener instead

Comment: Will this work if width is set to match parent?